# transform rotate not rotating multiple times as expected

Tags: css, svg, css-transforms

I'm having trouble making an SVG group rotate multiple times. If I specify 2520 degrees, I expect it to rotate seven times, as it does here for both an HTML and SVG element.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        .spin {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background: red;
        }
    
        .spin:hover {
          transform: rotate(2520deg);
          transition: transform 3s ease-out;
        }
        
        rect {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background: red;
        }
    
        g:hover {
          transform: rotate(2520deg);
          transform-origin: 50px 50px;
          transition: transform 3s ease-out;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="spin">
    
      </div>
      <svg>
        <g>
          <rect height="100" width="100" fill="blue" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm in a React project that's a bit complicated to post in a CodePen or whatnot. In my project, instead of rotating multiple times as in these examples, it always rotates *less* than one full rotation in either direction, no matter what huge number I use in the transform property. I think it's called short rotation in some contexts? Like it's using a modulus of 360 degrees, so it's rotating to the remainder of `x / 360`. So if I say rotate(2520deg), it doesn't appear to rotate at all, as `2520 % 360` is zero.

WHY ON EARTH WOULD THIS BEHAVIOR BE DIFFERENT IN MY PROJECT THAN IN THESE EXAMPLES? I don't even know where to start, but dismantling this thing to isolate the behavior would be tedious, unless there's something obvious out there. Where can I look? Thanks in advance.

Comment: PS: if my answer doesn't help, can you please post some way to reach out your project in order to do some testing? if you really can produce a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Temani It's obvious that that would be preferable. As I mentioned, I don't know how to go about that, because, as mentioned I do not know how to reproduce this. If I did, I wouldn't be here asking.

Comment: don't worry , are there any ways to try online your project?

Comment: *I don't know how to go about that, because, as mentioned I do not know how to reproduce this.* --> so how are you expecting us to help you? you have a problem that you cannot show us so there is no problem ...

Comment: @Berto99, Possibly at risk of violating contract or of not having the project live permanently somewhere.

Comment: well, in this case, try my solution and let me know, if it does not solve your problem, i'll try to find some other ways

Comment: @Temani, that's not logical. I assure you there is a problem. And it could be solved with something like some standards setting or something like that. Someone could know the answer right off the top of their head. I'm sure SOMEONE has experienced this, and it's probably a simple fix. I'm giving all the clues and information I have available to me.

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .. all we can do here is guessing. *you* have a problem but your question shows no problem. It's not about *you* here but the content you are showing. Your question as stated is off-topic. Even if by any chance someone is able to give a *random* fix that works for you it won't be helpful for anyone in the future because there is no clear problem to start with.

Comment: @Temani, I wouldn't in the least expect some *random* fix or hack of any kind. This *has* to be some simple setting somewhere. Please show me where it's not allowed to ask a question about a problem that can't be reproduced. What you've showed me are guidelines for asking better questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.*

Comment: Once I solve this, I'll reproduce the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually was because I was overriding another transform rule that looked like:

```
transform: scale(1);
```

It doesn't make sense to me that it would yield that result, but that's what it did in multiple browsers.

I solved it by setting the overridden rule to:

```
transform: none;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was recently met with this. This example does NOT work:

```
.spin:hover {transform: rotate(360) scale(1.2)}
.spin       {transform: rotate(0)   scale(1)}
```

I have already met such questions. The person says that the `rotate(...)` mechanism it breaks down just like that, for no reason. For me, too -- it worked yesterday, not today.

Two different ways to solve this:

1. Use `rotate(-1)`:

   ```
   .spin:hover {transform:rotate(360) scale(1.2)}
   .spin {transform:rotate(-1) scale(1)}
   ```

   Note that `rotate(0)` used to be perceived as a return to the initial state, now as the absence of rotation.
2. Use `scale(1.0)`:

   ```
   .spin:hover {transform:rotate(360) scale(1.2)}
   .spin {transform:rotate(0) scale(1.0)}
   ```

   Note that `scale(1)` gives an error, but `scale(1.0)` works.

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this:

```
g:hover {
  animation: 1s 3 spin;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: This did actually yield helpful results. It's helpful in problem solving, at least. I'll work with it and see if I can make it work.